# Collections.sort() not sort truely

Tags: java, android, collections

When i use Collections.sort() , it isnt sorted truely, 
this is my code :

```
matchedWords.addAll(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("matched_words"));
    TextView matchedTexts = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    matchedTexts.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    String text = "You have " + matchedWords.size() + " words in NewGsl Library";

    matchedTexts.setText(text);
    matchedTexts.append("\n");

    Collections.sort(matchedWords);
    for(String match : matchedWords)
    {
        matchedTexts.append( match.toLowerCase());
        matchedTexts.append("\n");
    }
```

result is :

```
1.ıf 
2.ıf
3.reading
4.a
5.a
6.about
.
.
.
```

Comment: How did you expect it to be sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
 Collections.sort(matchedWords, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {

            return lhs.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's work ! Thanks a lot for your help :)